# Using AppleScript to batch convert .pages to pdf

Tags: applescript, pdf, pages, file-conversion

I am needing to convert about 100 .pages documents to either pdf or docx.
With the AppleScript script below, I am able to open .pages documents from the folder that I select. However I receive the following error when trying to export.

**Question:** What is causing the error and how do I fix it?

**Error Message with personal information replaced:**

> error "Pages got an error: Can’t make alias \"Macintosh
>   HD:Users:Path:To:File:foo.pages\" into
>   type document." number -1700 from alias "Macintosh
>   HD:Users:Path:To:File:foo.pages." to
>   document

**Line of code producing the error:**

```
export this_file to exportFileName as PDF
```

**Script:**

```
set exportFileExtension to "pdf"
set this_folder to (choose folder with prompt "Pick the folder containing the files to process:") as string
tell application "System Events"
    set these_files to every file of folder this_folder
end tell
repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_files
    set this_file to (item i of these_files as alias)
    set this_info to info for this_file
    tell application "Finder"
        set {fType, nExt} to ({file type, name extension} of file this_file)
        set documentName to the name of this_file
        set exportFileName to documentName & "." & exportFileExtension
    end tell
    if nExt contains "pages" then
        tell application "Pages"
            open this_file
            export this_file to exportFileName as PDF
            close saving no
        end tell
    end if
end repeat
```

**###Update###:** I have [added this script to github](https://github.com/bountonw/UsefulScripts/tree/master/AppleScript) with the hopes of it benefiting others as it continues to be improved. Contributions appreciated.

Comment: Yes, indeed :) Never touched AppleScript before the major copy/paste from multiple sources exhibited here. I'm not using fType, but I am using nExt. can I just `set nExt to (name extension of file this_file)`? Regarding naming conventions, agreed. This is from the multiple sources that I copied from. I will clean that up. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the line of code producing the error with the following:

```
export front document to file (this_folder & exportFileName) as PDF
```

There were two issues here:

- export takes a document, so you need to pass it the document as opened by Pages.
- You gave the file name, but not a containing folder to put the file with this name, so concatenate this with the containing folder path so Pages knows where to export to.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to successfully export using the changes that you suggest. However, my code opens all 100 files before executing and does not close them.

Comment: @BrianWilson, Re: your comment... change `close saving no` to `close front document saving no`

Comment: hmm. Now  `set this_file to (item i of these_files as alias)` is **causing error message:** `error "Can’t make «class cpkg» \"Macintosh HD:Users:Path:to:file.pages:\" of application \"System Events\" into type alias." number -1700 from «class cpkg» "Macintosh HD:Users:Path:to:file.pages:" to alias`

Comment: Thanks for the help in answering the original questions with followups. The code is still very buggy, but the original problem has been solved. As a service to humanity, I am putting the script on github. [link](https://github.com/bountonw/UsefulScripts/blob/master/AppleScript/pagesToPDF.scpt)

Comment: Here is a better [link to github](https://github.com/bountonw/UsefulScripts/tree/master/AppleScript). I have included a text file so it is not necessary to download the .scpt file to see what is going on.